# xslt namspace related to copying some elements

Tags: xslt-2.0, saxon

So, I have a stylesheet that spends most of its time transforming elements from 'namespace a' to the xhtml namespace.

In one particular case, however, I want to allow the input vocabulary to include any xhtml element. From a schema standpoint, I've added an `<xs:any namespace="...."/>` for the xhtml namespace.

It looks like:

```
<btml:html-noscript xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <div style="display:inline;">
        <img height="1" 
             width="1" 
             style="border-style:none;" 
             alt="" 
             src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/1070015830/?label=FoKlCKDxiAIQ1sqc_gM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
    </div>
</btml:html-noscript>
```

The stylesheet uses `xsl:copy-of` to copy the children of the passthrough element into the output.

Saxon-B, which I am using (last release), seems sort of stupid about the namespaces. Even though the target namespace of the entire output document is the xhtml namespace, the output looks like:

```
<noscript>
    <div xmlns:btml="http://www.basistech.com/2010/btml/"
         xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
         style="display:inline;">
    <img height="1" 
              width="1" 
              style="border-style:none;" 
              alt="" 
              src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/1070015830/?label=FoKlCKDxiAIQ1sqc_gM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"></img>
    </div>
</noscript>
```

Note the pointless prefixes, instead of just putting out `<div ...>`. Note that the document element of the whole business ('html') defines `xmlns="ttp://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`.

Is there any way to neaten this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try whether doing `<xsl:copy-of select="node()" copy-namespaces="no"/>` helps (see http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#copy-of). If not then please post complete samples of XML input, and XSLT stylesheet allowing us to reproduce the problem, your snippets so far do not explain where for instance the `xmlns:xhtml="..."` in the result snippet on the `div` element comes from.

Comment: Martin, if you're suggesting that this might be a saxon-b defect, and that the developers are still maintaining saxon-b, I'll make a full test case and attach it to the tracker at sf.net.

Comment: It's hard to make a repro that fits in here. The stylesheet is part of a forest of interrelated complex styles sheets. However, I'll see what I can give you. A complete repro would be better suited to a bug report.

Comment: bmargulies, my suggestion is to use `copy-namespaces="no"`, that should prevent in scope but unused namespaces from being copied (as Alejandro has also explained by now). As for telling whether there is a bug, so far your snippets don't make much sense, the input snippet has a `btml:html-noscript` element without declaring that prefix `btml`, the XSLT snippet then does not process that `btml:html-noscript` element but rather a `btml:html-passthrough` instead.

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#scoping

> The scope of a namespace declaration
>   declaring a prefix extends from the
>   beginning of the start-tag in which it
>   appears to the end of the
>   corresponding end-tag, excluding the
>   scope of any inner declarations with
>   the same NSAttName part. In the case
>   of an empty tag, the scope is the tag
>   itself.

For your case, it means that `"http://www.basistech.com/2010/btml/"`  and `"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` namespace URIs bound to `btml` an `xhtml` prefixes are in scope for your `div` element unther `"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` default namespace.

Of course, as suggested by @Martin Honnen's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394136/xslt-namspace-related-to-copying-some-elements/5395173#5395173) `xsl:copy-of/@copy-namespaces` with  `"no"` as value will strip in scope namespace **not actually used** (i.e. in this element or its attribute's names).